# SwiftUI Search is not working on iPhone 13 Pro Max iOS 16

Tags: ios, search, swiftui

I've a jsonFile contain list of countries and created a function called **countryFromJson()** to read the data inside the json file, the problem is that the search is working normally on every devices except on **iPhone 13 Pro Max with iOS 16** the search isn't working, and I can't find what's wrong with it, is it the device or is it because the algorithm I write below?

```
struct CountryListView: View {
   @Binding var countryCode: String
   @Binding var countryFlag: String
   @Binding var countryName: String
    
   @State private var searchText = ""

   var body: some View {
       HStack {
           VStack {

               SearchBar(text: $searchText)
               
               List {
                   ForEach( countryFromJson().data.filter({ country in
                    
                       let fullCountryName = country.countryName.hasPrefix(searchText)
                       let countryCode = country.dialCode
                       return fullCountryName || searchText == "" || countryCode.hasPrefix(searchText)
                    
                   }), id: \.self) { country in
                       HStack {
                           Text(country.flag)
                           Text(country.countryName)
                           Spacer()
                           Text("+\(country.dialCode)")
                               .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                       }.background(Color.white)
                           .font(.system(size: 20))
                           .onTapGesture {
                               self.countryCode = "+\(country.dialCode)"
                               self.countryFlag = country.flag
                               let countryName = country.countryName
                               self.countryName = countryName
                               self.presentation.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                       }
                   }
               }
           }
       }
   }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciate, I just wanna know what is the problem with this because the search is working normally on every device I've tested, only iPhone 13 Pro Max with iOS 16 not work with the search.

###### Here's the picture of my list of country:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem that can cause the problem relate to search, the solution was simple: **Just convert those data to lowercase** and it solve my problem

```
let fullCountryName = country.countryName.lowercased().hasPrefix(searchText.lowercased())
let countryCode = country.dialCode.lowercased()
return fullCountryName || searchText == "" || countryCode.hasPrefix(searchText.lowercased())
```

Now I can search both uppercase and lowercase.